# How can I check a string with regex until I find a whitespace?

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex with the preg_replace function on PHP :

```
$str=preg_replace(
    '#\b((Hello ).+)#',
    '<a class="lforum" href="$1">$1</a>',
    $str);
```

It checks all strings that start with `Hello` and are followed by any kind of chars (at least one char, with repetition).

So for example :

```
Hello Mark \\ is checked
HelloMark  \\ is not checked
```

The problem now is that also this string is checked :

```
Hello Mark Cordi
```

because white space is a char, anyway.

I don't want this. Or, better, if the string is `Hello Mark Cordi`, it must replace only `Hello Mark`.

How can I do this? Thanks

**EDIT** Problem with newline

My actual function :

```
echo example(htmlentities($myString, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));

function example($str) {
    $str=preg_replace(
        '#((Hello )[^ \n]+)#',
        '<a class="lforum" href="$1">$1</a>',
        $str);

    return nl2br($str);     
}
```

If $myString is :

```
Hello Mario
Ciao
```

(notice the newline, so at the end of Hello Mario there is a \n) the output is this :

```
<a class="lforum" href="Hello Mario<br />">Hello Mario<br /></a><br />Ciao
```

instead of :

```
<a class="lforum" href="Hello Mario">Hello Mario</a><br />Ciao
```

So it add that \n with $1 on replace, and it shouldnt :(

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/ is your friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[^ ]` (everything but a whitespace) instead of `.`.

`[^abc]` means "*everything but a, b and c*". Here we use it with a single whitspace.

Edit (2):

[This](http://codepad.org/i6lxLpmW) is working:

```
  $str=preg_replace(
        '#(Hello [^\s\n<]+)#',
        '<a class="lforum" href="$1">$1</a>',
        $str);
```

It is ok for strings like this: `Mark<...`, `Mark\n...`, `Mark ...` (replace `...` with what you want).

`[^\s\n<]` means "everything but spaces (`\s`), newlines (`\n`), and `<`".

Comment: kwichz: yes you can avoid anthything, just put it in the box :: [^ \t\n\r+]

Comment: This also have a problem. If the string is `Hello Marco\nByeBye` it see it as a single word (so whitespace is not as newline). How can I fix this trouble? Thanks man

Comment: `[^ \n]+` means "_some characters (one or more) without whitespace or newline_". What's wrong ?

Comment: Uhm...but there is a problem : if I put that [^ \n] the ouput include the \n in the $1 ?!?!?

Comment: Added an example, so you can see my problem

Comment: In fact I don't understand your EDIT. Why \n is taken in consideration on $1 if its excluded by ^?

Comment: but I dont need what you have added in your edit 2. Just space and newline :)

Comment: I added `<` for `<br>`, `<br />`, etc.

Comment: Yeah I see, but the problem is at the origin. I get that `<br />` after `nl2br`, before there are the `\n`. But those `\n` shouldnt be added on replace (because, with `[^ \n]` I exclude them). Why it add them with `$1`? That's strange...

Comment: With my example and `$str="Hello Mark\nOLA"`, I [get](http://codepad.org/gh1lMDjp) `<a class="lforum" href="Hello Mark">Hello Mark</a>\nOLA` (`\n` is not printed in the source code).

Comment: :O Yeah in fact using [^\s\n] it works perfectly. With [^ \n] no! Would be nice understand why :)

Answer (score 3):

Replace only word characters, using `\w` instead of `.`:

```
$str=preg_replace(
    '#\b((Hello )\w+)#',
    '<a class="lforum" href="$1">$1</a>',
    $str);
```

Word characters are:

- `A-Za-z`
- `0-9`
- `_`

This is probably what you actually want, rather than just excluding white space.

Comment: @boudou You could add it: `[\w-]` says "word characters and hyphens".

Comment: @lonesomeday Yes, and if my name is _Diam's_, I can add  `[\w-']`. I think it's simpler to use  `[^ ]`.

Comment: @boudou `[^ ]` is a bit silly. How about new lines? How about tabs? How about non-breaking spaces?  Surely you should at least go for `\S` (non white-space). That said, I almost always prefer to specify what characters *are* allowed, rather than the ones that aren't.

Comment: Yes, but in my example I need all chars expect whitespace (and, of coure, newline). So [^ \n] should works (it should :))

Comment: @kwichz And open brackets? And close angle-brackets? And back-slashes? You want all of those as well? How about `%`? If you really want all characters except whitespace (including `(>\%`), use `\S`. Otherwise, define what you *do* want; it's much cleaner.

Comment: @lonesomeday Your answer is not correct, because if I try it with `"Hello Mark<br>OLA"`, the output is `<a class="lforum" href="Hello Mark">Hello Mark</a><br>OLA`. http://codepad.org/lLktPRLg

Comment: In fact I need to parse an HTML links, and It could get any kind of chars :) (Yeah, whitespace also, but is the only way to end the replace)

Comment: @lonesomeday: Sorry, I thought he wanted to have only `<a href="hello chuck">hello chuck</a>` and not the following.

Comment: Ehm no, I need the following as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, edit section and various comments I believe following code should work fine for you:

```
$str = "Hello Mario
Ciao";
var_dump(example(htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")));
function example($str) {
    $s=preg_replace(
        '~(Hello\W+[^\W]+)~s',
        '<a class="lforum" href="$1">$1</a>',
        $str);
    return nl2br($s);
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(52) "<a class="lforum" href="Hello Mario">Hello Mario</a>"
```

Important is to use `s` modifier with regex to match newlines as well and `\W` for matching whitespace + newline.

Comment: I don't understand that `\W+[^\W]+)` after Hello, to be honest :) Also : what's `$` at the end? :) P.s. anyway, the rest of the text should be printed as well : not checked and replaced, but printed :) (So also the Ciao)

Comment: Anyway : `#\b((Hello )[^ \n]+)\b#` seems to work weel, but I don't understand why it works and without \b not...

Comment: Edited my answer to NOT to match till end of string and print rest of string. Pls check.

Comment: Yeah, so its the same as [^\s\n], like boudou has suggested :) Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't think so. `\W` will match ANY non-word character not just `\s\n`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to match also non-word characters (so for example also .,!? and so on :)

Comment: `(Hello [^\s\n<])` is pretty weak check IMO. What if original string is `"Hello\nMario\nCiao"` OR `"Hello\tMario\nCiao"`. But of course its your code and you are the best judge :)

Comment: ? If the string is how you wrote, just the match is not done (and that's correct :))